# Implicit operator issue with struct in C#

Tags: c#, .net, struct, implicit-conversion

I am trying to define a helper class that acts as a trigger.

The behaviour is that when **first** tested for true/false, it should return true, and for all subsequent calls will be false (thus, will be used for one-time operations):

```
public struct Trigger
{
    private bool converted;
    private bool disposed;

    public static implicit operator bool(Trigger trigger)
    {
        if (trigger.disposed)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Value will only be true once.
        if (!trigger.converted)
        {
            trigger.converted = true;
            trigger.disposed = true;
        }

        return trigger.converted;
    }
}
```

The issue is, that the implicit operator **always returns true**

When changing from struct to class it works fine.

Is there anything special about structs that i am missing here, with respect to defining implicit operators ?

Comment: Protip: Dont mutate, replicate.

Comment: Most likely you're getting a copy of your struct somewhere when passing it to some function and that's why you're seeing that behavior.

Comment: Why are you defining it a `struct` if you don't want it to behave like a `struct`?

Comment: Well I wanted thid thing to behave as closely as possible to a bool (e.g: no null issues)

Comment: @lysergic-acid Just have your implicit operator support `null` (presumably treating it as `false`).

Comment: to @MarcinJuraszek comment: you getting a copy of your struct when passing it in your operator.

Comment: Structs that aren't immutable are just a *nightmare* for semantics; unless you *really, really* know what you are doing, structs should be immutable (meaning: the contents **never** change after creation)

Comment: This is nothing to do with operators, implicit or otherwise, and everything to do with the difference between a value type and a reference type (as multiple other comments have pointed out). You say it works fine as a class (as it should), and if you want to mutate the object on conversion (a sketchy idea in the first place, IMHO) then a class is more appropriate. So why not just make the type a class and be done with it? Since you already know how to fix this, it's hard to understand what the real question is, other than an overly broad request for a class on value types.

Comment: @MarcGravell: In cases where a type needs to represent a bunch of independent-but-related variables, a structure which is nothing more than a collection of exposed public fields will in many scenarios offer cleaner semantics than anything else.  What is problematic is the lack of any means by which mutable value types can forbid compilers from assuming that an implicit copy of a struct will be equivalent to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments to your quetion already contain the answer.

The reason is that **when a value type is passed as a parameter of a method (or of an "operator" in this case), a copy of the entire object is made**. So the update of your fields `converted` and `disposed` happens to the copy of the object. That copy is not kept when control leaves the method.

If you made a `ref` parameter, that would help, but that is not allowed in operators (for good reasons), so it would look like:

```
// just to explain, not a recommended "solution"
public static bool ToBool(ref Trigger trigger)  // ByRef parameter
{
    .... // change 'trigger' here and return value
}
```

Of course an instance method (or instance property) could also help, see the answer by James Curran.

---

It is instructive to see what happens if the struct contains a field of a reference type. I choose the reference type `bool[]` which is an array type. I want an array of length one which can be mutated. When the struct `Trigger` is passed by value, the "value" of the field is a reference to the same array instance.

```
// just to explain, not a recommended "solution"
public struct Trigger
{
    bool[] referenceTypeField; // meant to always hold a length-one array of bools

    public static Trigger GetNew()
    {
        return new Trigger { referenceTypeField = new[] { false, }, };
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Trigger trigger)
    {
        if (trigger.referenceTypeField == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Always construct Trigger through the GetNew method");

        if (trigger.referenceTypeField[0])
            return false;

        trigger.referenceTypeField[0] = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Test this with:

```
var t = Trigger.GetNew();
Console.WriteLine(t); // True
Console.WriteLine(t); // False
Console.WriteLine(t); // False
```

Of course we see that we really just move the `null` problem to the field. The `default(Trigger)` is invalid because its field is a `null` reference.

---

There is a **future version of C#** coming up in which structs can have zero-parameter instance constructors, and can have field initializers for instance fields. With that version of C# you could have:

```
public struct Trigger
{
    readonly bool[] referenceTypeField = new[] { false, };  // ALLOWED!

    public static implicit operator bool(Trigger trigger)
    {
        if (trigger.referenceTypeField == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Always construct Trigger properly");

        if (trigger.referenceTypeField[0])
            return false;

        trigger.referenceTypeField[0] = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

It is often said that mutable structs are evil (search for threads on that here on Stack Overflow) because of issues like yours. The best advice is to abandon the idea of having a mutable struct (and not use any of my example code above).

Comment: Can you provide reference of this claim: "There is a future version of C# coming up in which structs can have zero-parameter instance constructors, and can have field initializers for instance fields."? One point to not allow default constructor for value types is that no guaranty that it will be called: it is not called for array elements and class instance fields, and you can use `default(T)` to initialize any variable and bypass constructor call, even `new T()` `where T:struct` emit `initobj` instruction not a constructor call.

Comment: @PetSerAl See for example [New Features in C# 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx), in section _Parameterless constructors in structs_. When Visual Studio 2015 is released, this is part of C#, apparently. You can download the preview version and try it. I did not try it. Note that the example also uses auto-properties with no `set` accessor, and other fancy stuff. I can agree with you that this will confuse some developers. `default(Person)` will not run the constructor. `new Person()` will. With a constrained generic type ... try for yourself.

Comment: Prior to C# 6, if `T` is a type parameter, `new T()` is allowed if either ***(1)*** `T` has the value-type constraint `where T : struct`, or ***(2)*** `T` has the constructor constraint `where T : new()` in which case `new T()` will be the same as `default(T)` for value types. With C# 6 I suspect they will start to allow `new T()` to have a new meaning in the case where a zero-parameter non-static constructor exists for `T` a struct. I do not know if they are going to allow combining these two constraints, as in `where T : struct, new()`. As I said, try for yourself with their preview version.

Answer (score 1):

The cast-to-bool operator is forcing a copy, so it always sees a new Trigger object.

Force it to use the same one by making it an instance method.  (I did it as a property, but it could be a method as well).  I also simplified it a bit.

```
struct Trigger
{
    private bool triggered;

    public bool IsFresh
    { 
        get
        {
            bool t = this.triggered;
            this.triggered = true;
            return !t;
        }
    }
}   


void Main()
{
    Trigger T = new Trigger();

    var a = T.IsFresh;
    var b = T.IsFresh;
    var c = T.IsFresh;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: This makes the code "work", but having a mutating struct is just *asking* for more confusion and pain; not the best approach, IMO